# Whether there is validation data in the MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, mnist

When I was learning deep learning, the book whose author is Michael Nielsen, I checked its ode repository. There is a .py file named mnist_loader, the content as followed

```
"""
mnist_loader
~~~~~~~~~~~~

A library to load the MNIST image data.  For details of the data
structures that are returned, see the doc strings for ``load_data``
and ``load_data_wrapper``.  In practice, ``load_data_wrapper`` is the
function usually called by our neural network code.
"""

#### Libraries
# Standard library
import pickle
import gzip

# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    """Return the MNIST data as a tuple containing the training data,
    the validation data, and the test data.

    The ``training_data`` is returned as a tuple with two entries.
    The first entry contains the actual training images.  This is a
    numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries.  Each entry is, in turn, a
    numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784
    pixels in a single MNIST image.

    The second entry in the ``training_data`` tuple is a numpy ndarray
    containing 50,000 entries.  Those entries are just the digit
    values (0...9) for the corresponding images contained in the first
    entry of the tuple.

    The ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are similar, except
    each contains only 10,000 images.

    This is a nice data format, but for use in neural networks it's
    helpful to modify the format of the ``training_data`` a little.
    That's done in the wrapper function ``load_data_wrapper()``, see
    below.
    """


    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

And, I noticed that there has
 `training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f)`.
Actually, when i read the offical documentation, it refers that “The training set contains 60000 examples, and the test set 10000 examples.”.So, why mnist_loader set validation_data fetching data from dataset. How can it do it? Maybe I need to know the detail after unziping file, but I couldn't find any blogs to explain it in detail.

Looking forward to your exciting answers!

I have unzipped the dataset, it is consistent with offical documentation. And I wonder what happened when the code `training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f)` was executed?

Comment: The author explains in his book, "when I described the MNIST data earlier, I said it was split into 60,000 training images, and 10,000 test images. That's the official MNIST description. Actually, we're going to split the data a little differently. We'll leave the test images as is, but split the 60,000-image MNIST training set into two parts: a set of 50,000 images, which we'll use to train our neural network, and a separate 10,000 image validation set."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It dose have these exeplain in the book. Howerver, I can't get the hint that the test dataset was split into two parts accroding to the codes.

Comment: I just tried inputing the number of three data set. Here are the results, 50,000 training data , 10,000 validation data , 10,000 test data. It is as same as what the author discreb. If it will be the author's personal adjustment to the data set, which split the dataset into three parts?

Comment: Are you asking why the author split the training set into training & validation sets?  I expect that he describes that too, although I haven't read his book. A validation set is usually used for hyperparameter selection, or other tasks like early stopping for training neural networks.